# Can not upload ipa to appstore using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: ios, intellij-idea, air, ipa, application-loader

Maybe somebody can help me to solve my problem. I am using IntelliJ IDEA for developing adobe flash/air apps for a year without problems. But now I notice problem uploading ipa. Application Loader tells me:

Apple's web service operation was not successful

Unable to authenticate the package 775818462.itmsp

> ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)

I am using IntelliJ IDEA (Cardea) IU 133.609 for Windows. Any IDEA? :)

Thanks, Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find more information about this issue. The main change is that Apple announced  "Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK." In response to this change, the Adobe AIR team fixed the AIR SDK. You can see more [here](https://blogs.apache.org/flex/entry/building_apache_flex_apps_for). Solution is to download latest Flex SDK and AIR.